# Delete (don't hide) text annotations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, annotation

I feel like this question should have a really simple answer, but I can't find it anywhere.

I added an annotation to my map while experimenting with different buttons, and it wasn't at all what I wanted, so I tried to figure out how to delete it. All I could find was the instruction to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle visibility off, so I did that. The next day, while again trying to solve a different labeling problem, I hit the text annotation button again, but again, it wasn't at all what I wanted, so I tried to delete. But now I'm stuck because anytime I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, either the first annotation I accidentally created is visible, or the second one is.

How can I fully *delete* these annotations? There must be a way, right? I'm not stuck forever with these unwanted call-out boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which version of QGIS you're using, but in 2.10 at least there's a delete button on the dialog you use to edit the annotation, double click on the annotation 'bubble' to access it...

[image]

Also, if you have the annotation bubble selected (so you see grey squares at the corners) you can press <kbd>Del</kbd>. You an only do this on one annotation at a time though (you can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - select or <kbd>Shift</kbd> - select annotations)

Comment: Beautiful! It works! I'd tried right-clicking, don't know why I didn't try a double-click. Thanks. (And yes, I am using 2.10.)