# Unable to delete certain elements from my map

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18, annotation, mapcanvas

Can anyone help me get rid of these 2 boxes ?

I can't figure out how they showed up in the first place... I've remove the check marks next to all my layers and the boxes won't go away.

I'm getting desperate as I would rather not have to start over from scratch.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this answer? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/161961/delete-dont-hide-text-annotations-in-qgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [annotations](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#annotation-tools). To delete an annotation:

1. Select the annotation button at the end of the Attributes toolbar.
   [image]
2. Double click on the annotation to open the annotation editing window. Click "delete." [image]

Annotations are a useful way to add text or images to a map, unless you add them by accident, in which case they're really annoying. [In QGIS 3.x](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?#annotation-tools), you can link an annotation to a particular map layer, so it only displays when that layer is active.