# Find source of annotations in order to delete in QGIS

Tags: qgis, annotation

I accidentally created these annotations while trying to measure distances and would like to delete them. This article mentions double-clicking, but this does not work for me (Version 3.22.6). Is there a way to select these another way or find the source layer to turn them off or delete them completely? Is there a better source for how best to create annotations?

Double click article [Delete (don't hide) text annotations in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/161961/delete-dont-hide-text-annotations-in-qgis)

[image: Annotations in question]

Edit: How to delete text annotations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using at least QGIS 3.22.x, if you double-click the annotation, you will find a delete button at the bottom of the window where you can delete the annotation. It works with `Text annotations`.

[image]

For other annotation types like `Create Text at Point`, `Create Marker`, `Create Line`, etc., you can use `Modify Annotations` [image] to select those types and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button on your keyboard.

Comment: This worked by selecting text annotations tool, doubleclicking, then deleting with pop up window shown here. 

You can also single select and press the delete key on keyboard. 

View > toolbars > Annotations Toolbar: Text annotations. Thank you.