# How do I get rid of stray points with box labels in QGIS 3.22?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, point, labeling

I'm working on a project on QGIS 3.22.1 with isochrone maps. There are two red points with captionless labels that I can't find a way to get rid of, even after I've unselected all my data layers. FYI, the layers are vector data from the City of Chicago Data Portal and NYC OpenData, as well as isochrone polygons generated by the ORS Tools plugin. The points spontaneously popped up while I was downloading the ORS Tools and QuickOSM plugins, and I don't know if they have anything to do with them. Here's an image of the issue below.

[image: Image of my QGIS monitor with all layers unselected. There are two stray points with captionless labels that I can't find a way to get rid of, even after unselecting all data layers.]

Comment: These are just text annotations. With the annotations tool activated ('T' inside a square speech balloon. It's the 3rd tool action from the right just above your canvas) just click on the annotation to select it and hit delete key.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/442705/63384) help?

Comment: The text annotation solutions works. Thank you so much, Ben!