# The annotation tool is not in my attributes toolbar QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, annotation, text

I am needing to delete two text boxes I added. I am unable to select them, and for soon reason the annotation tool is not in my attributes toolbar. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the `Menu Toolbar`, and activate the `Annotations Manu`:

[image]

To delete the annotations, you can refer to the answer in [Find source of annotations in order to delete in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/442705/63384)