Cannot select or delete annotations in QGIS
I added two annotations to a map project in QGIS, and I cannot select or delete them. I cannot locate the annotations layer in the Layers panel, nor in the Layer Styling panel. This must be an easy fix, but I can't find a way to select or delete them.

Did you have a look at older questions like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/161961/delete-dont-hide-text-annotations-in-qgis?

If you put the annotation into the map view using Edit - Add Annotation, use that command again to edit or delete any annotations. with a double click over each.  If you put the annotation into a layout then you will have to go to that layout to select and delete it.

I ended up editing the .qgs file in a text editor and deleting the annotations statements.

I had the same issue.  I solved it by:

'Hide All Layers" in the main view. This left only the offending annotations visible (that seemingly were not associated with any particular layer).
Activate the text annotation button in the Annotations tool bar (the one with the 'T' inside a rectangular speech bubble type box).
Select the offending annotation and hit delete.
(Make sure you now unselect the 'T' Text Annotation button or it'll just add another annoying annotation as soon as you click the screen)
Switch the layers you need back on.

Hopefully Bob's yer Uncle.
